# Object Required error at seemingly random locations

Tags: vba, object

I get this error only in specific spots, where it doesn't seem it should matter. For instance, In the first case, where I set **timevals**, the program runs fine. In the second case, where I set **timevals** again, I get the 424 Error.

I tried moving the **Set timevals = time(mrCell.column)** outside of my **Select**, as it does not need to be inside, calling the function for every single case (it can call it once, that's all that's needed..) but I am greeted with the error there as well. It only seems to work inside the Select, and only in certain areas.

```
                    'MsgBox .Value
                    Set timevals = time(mrCell.column)
                        
                    time_start = timevals.item("start")
                    MsgBox time_start
                    
                    time_stop = timevals.item("stop")
                    MsgBox time_stop
                    'MsgBox .Value
                    
                Case Is = "VM554 SAAnesSx - PtCare (Groups 12-14)"
                    MsgBox .Value
                    MsgBox mrCell.column
                    
                    Set timevals = time(mrCell.column)
                    
                    
                    time_start = timevals.item("start")
                    MsgBox time_start
                    
                    time_stop = timevals.item("stop")
                    MsgBox time_stop
                    MsgBox .Value
```

Here is the majority of the code.

```
    Set Selected = Selection.Cells
    Dim timevals As Collection
    
    Dim time_start As String
    Dim time_stop As String
    For Each mrCell In Selected
        With mrCell
            Select Case .Value
            ' Here, we'll have to manually input the names (from the other macro that labeled everything..)
                Case Is = "VM569 AgAn Lab G 12-14"
                    'MsgBox .Value
                    Set timevals = time(mrCell.column)
                        
                    time_start = timevals.item("start")
                    MsgBox time_start
                    
                    time_stop = timevals.item("stop")
                    MsgBox time_stop
        
                Case Is = "VM570 AgAn2"
                    'MsgBox .Value
                    Set timevals = time(mrCell.column)
                        
                    time_start = timevals.item("start")
                    MsgBox time_start
                    
                    time_stop = timevals.item("stop")
                    MsgBox time_stop
                    ' MsgBox .Value
                    
                Case Is = "VM571 Therio"
                    'MsgBox .Value
                    Set timevals = time(mrCell.column)
                        
                    time_start = timevals.item("start")
                    MsgBox time_start
                    
                    time_stop = timevals.item("stop")
                    MsgBox time_stop
                    'MsgBox .Value
                    
                Case Is = "VM552 SAM2"
                    'MsgBox .Value
                    Set timevals = time(mrCell.column)
                        
                    time_start = timevals.item("start")
                    MsgBox time_start
                    
                    time_stop = timevals.item("stop")
                    MsgBox time_stop
                    'MsgBox .Value
                    
                Case Is = "VM597.3 PopTherio Lec"
                    'MsgBox .Value
                    Set timevals = time(mrCell.column)
                        
                    time_start = timevals.item("start")
                    MsgBox time_start
                    
                    time_stop = timevals.item("stop")
                    MsgBox time_stop
                    'MsgBox .Value
                    
                Case Is = "VM554 SAAnesSx - PtCare (Groups 12-14)"
                    MsgBox .Value
                    MsgBox mrCell.column
                    
                    Set timevals = time(mrCell.column) ' Error here
                    
                    
                    time_start = timevals.item("start")
                    MsgBox time_start
                    
                    time_stop = timevals.item("stop")
                    MsgBox time_stop
                    MsgBox .Value
                   
                End Select
        End With
    Next
```

And here is the time function:

```
Function time(column As Long)
    'Delcare Variables
    Dim c As New Collection
    Dim item As Variant
    Dim key As String
    
    Dim eg_start As String
    Dim eg_stop As String
    
    Dim ni_start As String
    Dim ni_stop As String
    
    Dim te_start As String
    Dim te_stop As String
    
    Dim el_start As String
    Dim el_stop As String
    
    'instantiate them
    
    '8-9
    eg_start = "8:09AM"
    eg_stop = "9:02AM"
    
    '9-10
    ni_start = "9:09AM"
    ni_stop = "10:02AM"
    '10-11
    te_start = "10:09AM"
    te_stop = "11:02AM"
    '11-12
    el_start = "11:09AM"
    el_stop = "12:02PM"
    
    Select Case column
        Case Is = 8
            key = "start"
            item = eg_start
            c.Add item, key
            
            key = "stop"
            item = eg_stop
            c.Add item, key
            
            Set time = c
            
            
        Case Is = 9
            key = "start"
            item = ni_start
            c.Add item, key
            
            key = "stop"
            item = ni_stop
            c.Add item, key
            
            Set time = c
            
        Case Is = 10
            key = "start"
            item = te_start
            c.Add item, key
            
            key = "stop"
            item = te_stop
            c.Add item, key
            
            Set time = c
            
        
        Case Is = 11
            key = "start"
            item = el_start
            c.Add item, key
            
            key = "stop"
            item = el_stop
            c.Add item, key
            
            Set time = c
        Case Else
            key = "start"
            item = "N/A"
            c.Add item, key
            
            key = "stop"
            item = "N/A"
            c.Add item, key
   
    End Select
    MsgBox "goodbye"
End Function
```

Comment: You shouldn't use time as the name of the function as there is already a VBA function Time. Also, why aren't you returning anything from the function?

Comment: There's no `Set time = c` in the `Case Else` portion of the `Select Case`. You could probably just `Set time = c` once, after `End Select`, instead of individually in ever `Case`.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks for that.. In my hours of debugging I didnt realize this. Adding Set time = c at the end of the function fixed my issue. Much appreciated.

Comment: @norie, I wasnt aware there was a "Time" function. Thanks for bringing that to my attention. I will change the name to avoid confusion.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This site doesn't offer proof-reading services for faulty code. Therefore your code is too voluminous to be handled properly here. Some errors have been pointed out in the comments above. I want to address the volume of your misnamed and faulty function `Time`. Here is a version of it cut down to the required length.

```
Function GetTimes(Clm As Long) As Times
    ' 232
    ' Start and End will both be 0 if Clm <8 or >11
    
    Dim StartTime As Double
    
    If (Clm >= 8) And (Clm <= 11) Then
        StartTime = TimeSerial(Clm, 0, 0)
    End If
    
    With GetTimes
        .Start = StartTime
        If StartTime Then .End = TimeSerial(Clm + 1, 2, 0)
    End With
End Function
```

It takes the column number in the argument as the start hour and then adds an hour and 2 minutes to that for the end time. If the column (hour) < 8 or > 11 both start and end will be 0.

Your Collection doesn't work with *Key* and *Item* like a Dictionary but what you want is a *Type*. The *Type* must be declared at the top of the module, before any procedure (but after `Option Explicit`). This is the code.

```
Option Explicit

Private Type Times
    Start   As Double
    End     As Double
End Type
```

The function `GetTimes` uses this `Type`. Therefore it won't work without the above declaration. For testing purposes use the little procedure below. You can assign different numbers to the variable `Clm` and read the return values in the *Immediate* pane. The code also shows you how to convert hours (Long data type) and minutes (integers) to Double and then read the Double as time. Paste this procedure ***below*** the `Type` declaration.

```
Private Sub Test()

    Const TimeFormat    As String = "hh:mm"
    Dim MyTime          As Times
    Dim Clm             As Long                 ' Test column
    
    Clm = 10            ' change for testing
    MyTime = GetTimes(Clm)
    With MyTime
        If .Start Then
            Debug.Print "Start = "; Format(.Start, TimeFormat) & Chr(13) & _
                        "  End = "; Format(.End, TimeFormat)
        Else
            Debug.Print "Start = Stop" & Chr(13) & "  End = N/A"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I guess my first error would be using the function name "time", I wasn't aware there was a  default function called "Time". I am not trying to get the "time" as you are assuming I am. This is a custom function I have written

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have a "Default" Set for my variable "time". Adding `Set time = c` after the `End Select` solved my issue.

Also changing the name of the function away from `time` as it can be confusing with the default function `Time`. (Was no part of the issue, but, hey.)